# How to add a new horse type

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I tried adding an edited image of horse with red eyes, it did not appear. Even though I had renamed it `(horse_black1)`.
When the original horse, `(horse_black)` was deleted and replaced by the edited, it worked fine. The problem with this was that no normal black horse could appear. Does Anyone know how you can have both types of horses without losing any variant, just adding a new one?

Answer (score 2):

You can't add a new horse type without modding the game, you can just edit it using resource packs (like you did).

Comment: Does modding the game have any bad effect ?

Comment: @Jacob it can cause all sorts of unexpected stuff.

Comment: Can I use multiple modes at the same time or just one at a time ?? Sorry for the frequent questions and thanks for your help :D

Comment: @Jacob You can use multiple, yes. It might cause more bugs though. By "all sort of unexpected stuff", I meant that there will be more bugs

Answer (score 1):

You would have to get rid of at least one.  Instead of replacing the black one you could replace a different colored one if the black one is important in your world.

You could also use  skeleton or zombie horses because they are not original and have to be summoned.  You can change there texture instead then spawn them with these commands:

```
Tamed Zombie Horse: /summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:3,Tame:1}

Untamed Zombie Horse: /summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:3}

Tamed Skeleton Horse: /summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:4,Tame:1}

Untamed Skeleton Horse: /summon EntityHorse ~ ~ ~ {Type:4}
```

Comment: I think skeleton horses can be found in survival, see here: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Horse#Skeleton_trap

Comment: Wow, guess so, but they can still be used as a texture change because they are really rare.

Comment: I would use zombie horses as they cant be spawned in survival by natural means

Comment: but skeleton horses can be used ;)